# Bind complex object from query string in post request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding, .net-6.0, query-string

I have a class for holding both raw and encrypted values from query parameters:

```
public class SID
{
    [FromQuery(Name = "sidInt")]
    public int RawValue { get; set; }

    [FromQuery(Name = "sid")]
    public string EncryptedValue { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator int(SID model)
    {
        return model.RawValue;
    }
}
```

Having this I can successfully use it as a parameter for get requests:

```
/// GET: /{controller}/index?sid=my-encrypted-string
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index(SID id){ 
    int resourceId = id;
    //rest of the action code 
}
```

Only encrypted value is provided in query string, raw integer value is automatically decrypted and added to the query string in my custom middleware. Notice that thanks to named `[FromQuery]` attributes I can use any parameter name in the action.
So far so good. But now I want to use the same `SID` class as a property in model for post request:

```
public class MyPostModel {
    [Required]
    [FromQuery]
    public SID Id { get; set; }     

    public string Name { get; set; } // posted in body
    // rest of the properties
}

/// POST: /{controller}/index?sid=my-encrypted-string + other fields in the body
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(MyPostModel model){ 
    int resourceId = model.Id;//model.Id is null here
    //rest of the action code 
}
```

But unfortunately I cannot make it working, Id in the model is not bound. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. Is it possible? Do I need a custom model binder for this(I hope not, I want to use `SID` class as a property for several models and for different actions)?

Of course I can add sid parameter to the post action and reassign it in the action body explicitly but it looks wrong and too verbose:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(SID id, MyPostModel model){ 
    model.Id = id;//id is correctly populated but model.Id is not
    //rest of the action code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that parameter is called "sid" and property in MyPostModel is "Id". Aside from that, I don't see any reason why it would not work. Can you change your MyPostModel:

```
public class MyPostModel {
    [Required]
    [FromQuery(Name = "sid")]
    public SID Id { get; set; }     

    public string Name { get; set; } // posted in body
    // rest of the properties
}
```